# Possible to change Etherscan verified source after initially verified?

Tags: etherscan, verify

Is it possible to change the *comments* in verified contract source on Etherscan once the contract source has already been verified?

It isn't the Solidity source itself that I'd like to change.  Just a comment.

I've tried verifying again, but receive the message:

`The Contract Source code for 0x... has already been verified.`

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so. If you could, then anyone could come along, copy the source code, and reverify it with completely different comments, which opens up for all types of attacks, including phishing. You could possibly contact Etherscan directly and they might let you replace the code if you can prove that you're the creator of the contract.

Comment: What I don't understand  is that it seems to me anyone can theoretically verify your contract as long as they do it *before* you do. Consider this scenario: 1. you deploy the contract. 2. (while you are preparing to verify&publish the source code which chances are you do manually) a bot detects that a contract has been deployed, decompiles it, adds spammy/phishing comments, and publishes it (yes it has to try a few different compiler versions). 3. you're screwed, and cannot publish the correct source code of your own contract. Or what am I missing?

Comment: On "If you could, then anyone could come along, copy the source code, and reverify it with completely different comments": . . . . . it's enough for Etherscan to just do the simple ownership check via account signature, from that account that deployed the smart contract. I don't understand why don't they provide this function to date, as changing comments by OWNERs, or fixing, for instance, uploaded typos makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't do this. Because etherscan will check your deployed contract byte  code with  current submitted code(compile version of byte code), if booth are same then only they will save your code to etherscan db.

Why they are doing:

1. Contracts are immutable, once contract is deployed in eth network  you can't change.
2. Competitor/hacker can copy the verified code and change your comments and resubmit your code. That may leads some more complications.

Better contract etherscan.io team. For explain the issue for change req.

Comment: The question wasn't about changing the code, it was about changing the *comments*.

Comment: @flygoing: correct.  Thanks to both for your feedback.  Contacted Etherscan.  Let's see if they have a mechanism for verifying my contract ownership.  Cheers.